# JQuery .scrollTop() and .offset().top issue: how it work? How to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achieve some kind of smooth scrolling, so I made this script:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var sclink = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.menu').animate({
        scrollTop: $(sclink).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

The problem? When I click on the 'a' the `offset.top()` value changes in another weird value and toggle between them? Why does this happen and how do I resolve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/9SDLw/2947/

I think the problem is with the `scroll.top()` that gets the value in another way... 
jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/2950/

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var sclink = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.menu').animate({
        scrollTop: $(sclink).position().top
    }, 500);
    logit('Anchor: '+sclink+'; Offset top value: <b>'+$(sclink).offset().top+'</b>')
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Please use scrollTop();

Comment: Look at this page: it can help you to learn how to make smooth scrolling: http://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/doc/demo-smoothscroll.html

Comment: $(this).attr('href') : string, replace with $(this)

Comment: Solved here: http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/5474/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `position` instead of `offset`.

The reason is `offset` is relative to the viewport, as such it looks like you've scrolled too far, but this is because the top of your viewport area is being obscured by your layout, so `offset` is actually not what you want, instead, `position` is.

You should also add a reference to `stop` before calling `animate` to ensure if a user clicks in quick succession the behaviour is as expected (the animation queue is essentially flushed)

With that in mind your HTML also needs some work- the clickable link hasnt got closing tags for example.

Change your scrolling code to:

```
$('.menu').stop(true,true).animate({
    scrollTop: $(sclink).position().top
}, 500);
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/9SDLw/2952/)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I implemented your solution to an live demo here: http://socialtab.it/fb/ristopiper/menu/ but the scrolling still working bad D:

Comment: You've kind of changed the parameters of the question by adding a link with totally different code than that you originally posted :S - you're asking to debug a webpage which isnt on-topic for SO Im afraid :(

Comment: You may want to try to deconstruct your code into smaller sections and debug each in turn, it seems to be working for some links vs others, try to identify any differences between them that may be causing this

Comment: But here if you want simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/2964/ Thanks for help ^^ I trying to debuf since 6h with no result...for me it's no sense xD So that's why I asked on Stackoverflow